# Running synchronous commands to between two sql servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running a stored procedure on server1 from my application. The stored procedure does a bunch of stuff and populate a table on server2 with the result from the procedure.

I'm using linked server to accomplish this.

When the stored procedure is done running the application continues and tries to do some manipulation of the result from the stored procedure.

My problem is that the results from the stored procedure has not been completely inserted into the tables yet, so the manipulation of the tables fails.

So my question is. Is it possible to ensure the insert into on the linked server is done synchronous? I would like to have the stored procedure not return until the tables on the linked server actually is done.

Comment: HOw will sproc return the control to the application untill it finishes the insert operation?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in my stored procedure that had the procedure return too early. I will add details in my own answer to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this strange behavior. There was a line of code in my stored procedure added during debug that did a select on a temporary mem table before the data in the same table was written to the linked server.

When the select statement was run, the control was given back to my application and at the same time the stored procedure continued running. I guess the stored procedure was running synchronously from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an output parameter of the first procedure. When the table is create on the second server the output parameter value will be return to your application and indicates the operation is ready.

If the things are difficult then this you can try setting a different isolation level of your store procedure:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx